# How to integrate .Net application to ADCS using API

Tags: pki

We have to integrate own app to MS ADCS environment for autoenrollment digital certificates. Is there any guide to integrate our app to MS Certificate Authority using API?

Comment: Define "own app" Is it written in Java, Cobol or PHP (or something else....) ?

Comment: My app was developed in .Net C#